# Which files are added to the APK and iOS bundle React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bundle

In our project root, we have keys for uploading the app bundles to the app stores using Fastlane. We noticed that we have hard-coded secrets in the Fastlane files.

So our question is, which files are added to the app bundle when building a production release? Since this can be decompiled to extract these files/secrets?

Also, our production .keystore is in the android/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

A React Native production build contains only the bundled JavaScript and some assets like fonts and images. The thing the JavaScript has loaded in its own files. I mean `import backBg from 'assests/backbg.jpg`, for example.

So it means all files that you are seeing in the project folders are development files, and a few of them will be in the production build.

About the native side, it is true too. Fastlane configurations file, environment variables etc. all of them are for development. for production only some `xml` files and all `java/kt`, and `m/mm/swift` files will be compiled into binaries.

Comment: thanks. so I should not be worried?

Comment: @Dirk, No, at all.